# How to stop duplicating code on same page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am really new to asp.net and I have pages where I find I am duplicating code which I don't want to.  In plain c# I would write a function am call it from where ever I want to but in asp.net it doesn't seem to allow me to do this.  What's the way to do this

An example of my code duplication is found below

```
protected void Step02SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Session["Step02AllServices"] = Step02AllServices.Checked;
     Session["Step02ContentUploading"] = Step02ContentUploading.Checked;
     Session["Step02ContentLayoutChecking"] = Step02ContentLayoutChecking.Checked;
     Session["Step02TestingVariousBrowsers"] = Step02TestingVariousBrowsers.Checked;
     Session["Step02TestingFunctionality"] = Step02TestingFunctionality.Checked;
     Session["Step02ResponsiveLayouting"] = Step02ResponsiveLayouting.Checked;
     Session["Step02ResponsiveTesting"] = Step02ResponsiveTesting.Checked;
}           

protected void Step02PreviousButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Session["Step02AllServices"] = Step02AllServices.Checked;
     Session["Step02ContentUploading"] = Step02ContentUploading.Checked;
     Session["Step02ContentLayoutChecking"] = Step02ContentLayoutChecking.Checked;
     Session["Step02TestingVariousBrowsers"] = Step02TestingVariousBrowsers.Checked;
     Session["Step02TestingFunctionality"] = Step02TestingFunctionality.Checked;
     Session["Step02ResponsiveLayouting"] = Step02ResponsiveLayouting.Checked;
     Session["Step02ResponsiveTesting"] = Step02ResponsiveTesting.Checked;
}
```

Comment: refactoring: extract method http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html

Comment: Put those sessions into an array, boom, you can send the array as parameter for your function. In your function you have the .Checked array ready to set.

Comment: create a private method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you create another function ?

```
protected void Step02SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myfunction();
}           

protected void Step02PreviousButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myfunction();
}

protected void myfunction()
{
    Session["Step02AllServices"] = Step02AllServices.Checked;
     Session["Step02ContentUploading"] = Step02ContentUploading.Checked;
     Session["Step02ContentLayoutChecking"] = Step02ContentLayoutChecking.Checked;
     Session["Step02TestingVariousBrowsers"] = Step02TestingVariousBrowsers.Checked;
     Session["Step02TestingFunctionality"] = Step02TestingFunctionality.Checked;
     Session["Step02ResponsiveLayouting"] = Step02ResponsiveLayouting.Checked;
     Session["Step02ResponsiveTesting"] = Step02ResponsiveTesting.Checked;
}
```